# Data Loader : the operation has fully completed there were 0 successful inserts and 2 errors

Tags: salesforce1-app, data-loader, salesforce-id, data

I have problem when I insert file .csv via data loader 
after mapping
[image]
I get : the operation has fully completed there were 0 successful inserts and 2 errors
[image]

I don't know what's the problem exactly.

***the new error***
[image]

Comment: Check your object for unique fields. You are trying to write a duplicate value in that field for each of this records. You can check the sf record id at the end of the error message to find the corresponding 'duplicate' record.

Comment: The two errors are : ""date de contrat : date non valide : Sun Deb 02 00:00:00 GMT 16 """
But in the CSV file i made : 25/02/2015

Comment: See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm for accepted date formats.

Comment: Hi the file which you are inserting contains invalid date format
Although salesforce is trying to parse it but after parsing created date is not valid
Update file date in correct format here is the [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: Thank you very uch for your help ,,,,Now it'is a new error :""" Stagiaire : Valeur d 'ID de type incorrect : iman """" ... please return to the question I updat the new error

Comment: It looks like Stagiaire: Valeur d'ID isn't a text field and so your values of iman and imaaaan are invalid. Perhaps its a lookup field?